# Magento, can't display getSku() on success page

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to echo getSku() on the success page, but it returns 0. I can use getGrandTotal() or getId(), but I can't get getSku() to work. Any ideas?

The code:

```
$customer_email = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                    ->getCollection()
->getItemsCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending_payment')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email',array('like'=>$customer_email));

foreach($collection as $order){
    //do something
    //echo round($order->getGrandTotal(),2) . " ";
    $sum += $order->getSku();

} echo $sum;
```

Comment: are you getting id using getId() ??

Comment: Hi, yes, by getId() function

Answer (score 0):

This is because the full product isn't being loaded. The following code should do the trick for you:

```
foreach($collection as $order){
    // load the product from the ID
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($order->getProductId());

    //do something
    //echo round($order->getGrandTotal(),2) . " ";
    $sum += $product->getSku();
}
```

I'm not sure if adding the SKU is what you want to do though as the SKU would usually be alphanumeric? Sorry if I've misunderstood!

Comment: yes, the SKU is what I want to list. Unfortunately, the solution still returns 0 :(

Answer (score 0):

so you can load that product using that id and then get sku as well.

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

    echo $productModel->getSku();
```

don't forget to like my answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Don't do what the other questions are suggesting, loading models in loops is bad an should be avoided at all cost. Neither should you call `getItemsCollection` inside your loop.

Your current code doesn't even run, because there is no method called `getItemsCollection` inside an order collection. That's part of the order object.

Assuming you just want all skus for orders that are pending payment for a particular customer, you could use something like:

```
// Get all orders matching our conditions.
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending_payment')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', array('like' => $customer_email));

// Get all items associated with those orders.
$itemCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', array('in' => $orderCollection->getAllIds()));

// Now do whatever you want with your order item.
foreach ($itemCollection as $item) {
    var_dump($item->getSku());                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

Comment: thx for the reply. But now, instead of getting '0' I get an empty string like the product was without SKU id. I'm on pending payment site for the order and they list the SKU of the product, but I still can't display it via getSku() method

Answer (score 0):

Load order by using  session on success.phtml

```
    $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
Now load order 
 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
        $order->load($lastOrderId);

ordered_items = $order->getAllItems(); 
foreach($ordered_items as $item){  
   //item detail 
    echo $item->getItemId(); //product id   
  echo $item->getSku();    
 echo $item->getQtyOrdered(); 
//ordered qty of item    
 echo $item->getName();  
   // etc. 
}
```